# Route.php line 279: Class App\Http\Controllers\PaymentController does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, paypal

I'm trying to install payment with Paypal API on my website using this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q5Xb5r4MUB8

I'm getting an error when i wantto access this URL: /payment

> Route.php line 279: Class App\Http\Controllers\PaymentController does not exist

I've checked that the PaymentController is actually in App\Http\Controller
I've tried a **composer dumpautoload** and a **php artisan optimize**

Something wierd is that not any class from **\app** are referenced in **vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php**...

Here is the begining of my PaymentController.php file:

```
<?


namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Paypalpayment;

class PaymentController extends Controller {
```

Comment: You file doesn't start with a php tag. Replace it with <?php

Comment: That's it ! (want to hit my head on a wall haha) Thanks man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your opening file tags to `<?php`